# Quest' remarks on getting data from request

Tags: c#, xml, post

I need to get data from other server, with post method.
When i try it with fiddler, i get the data correctly but with c#, i have a problem, 
getting question remark instead of hebrew chars.

This is my C# code:

```
    private static string PostForm(string Host, string Body)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Host);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='windows-1255'";

        byte[] bytes = (Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)).GetBytes(Body);
        //bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255"), bytes);

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

        stream.Dispose();
        reader.Dispose();

        return result;
    }
```

This method get the host address, and xml content as string on the Body parameter.

In fiddler i write the xml on the document body, and nothing more but it works perfect.

Any suggestions? 10x

Comment: You could try adding ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-8 to your code, since some characters in windows-1255 are not included. (http://www.nirdagan.com/hebrew/characters/). If it solves your problem I can post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, i added Encoding.GetEncoding(1255) to the SteamReader, and it fix it.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Endocding to the streamReader and it fix it.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1255));
```